# Win Phone 8 : Navigating Only One Time

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm on windows phone 8 project. Doing it with xaml in visual studio.

I have 4 pivot items in this project.

I want to navigate the home page (my first pivot item) with

menu on bottom of phone;

```
<shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="Images/appbar_home.png" Text="Home" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_2"/>
```

and on click event i wrote this;

```
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?PivotMain.SelectedIndex = 0", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

When i run the program, it works nice, when i go other pivot items, and click that home button, it goes, but if i walk around again and click button, it doesnt work. Why ?

I need to solve this.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having this problem because you are doing it wrong.

`NavigationService.Navigate` is meant to navigate between XAML Files, not reload them. The phone doesn't like to reload the same page over and over.

What you want to do instead is set the current selected index to the first page.

Reference:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot(v=vs.105).aspx

It will look something like this

```
        private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PivotControlName.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

Comment: ....Replace pivotControlName with the name of your pivot control... Also SelectedIndex should be Cased like I wrote it

Comment: thanks for the answers mate. I started win phone today. sorry for noobie questions :)

Comment: lol no worries. Its a great platform. Just make sure that you research as much as you can before you post on here. People will nuke you if its a question that is easily researched.